# Samba4 AD DC for roaming profiles or openLDAP? which is better?

Tags: ldap, openldap, samba4

I am looking to create roaming profiles for Ubuntu client machines, about 100 machines are there. 200+ users. Is it better to use Samba4 AD DC  or openLDAP ? OR should I use them in conjunction?
I want centralised management of users and passwords as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since your setup seems to be using Linux only , I would suggest looking into [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/About)

Instead of running a pure OpenLDAP solution or Using Active directory

FreeIPA contains a ldap backend, kerberos DNS and a administrative web-interface but all wrapped together in a more easily managed solution

Similarly to Active directory it supports:

- Delegate permission handling of groups to users ( to lessen admin
  burden)
- Support for nested groups
- Full multi master data replication support